# Mongoid / Mongodb and querying embedded documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have `Author` and `Book` models.

An `Author` has many embedded `Books`.

Can I query the embedded `Books`, or do I have to fetch `Authors` first to get `Books`?

Answer (score 50):

You can query embedded documents, just qualify the name. Now, this will return all Authors that have books that match your query.

If Author is defined as having many :books (and book is an embedded::document)

```
@authors_with_sewid = Author.where("books.name" => "sewid").all
```

You'd then need to iterate over the authors and extract the books.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. What if I have a mixture of embedded and referenced documents, can I also query for referenced documents? For example, the Author model has a creator-field, that contains the ID of an user. Is it possible to do 'Author.where("book.name" = "sewid").and("creator.username" => "example")'? A first try failed.

Comment: Once they are referenced objects, you would need a Join. And there are no Joins in mongodb land.

Comment: The best thing to do in that case is denormalize your data and store the creator username with the Author.

Comment: Just a quick notice. It should be ("books.name" => "sewid"), as the author has many embedded books.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott is it possible to just return the books, and not have to iterate over the authors to extract?

Comment: Note that more complex queries can still be done, like this: `all_of({:'books.name' => 'name'}, {:'books.author' => /joe/i})`

Comment: it also works in this format: `('book.name': 'sewid')`