# How do I search within an array of hashes inside a hash by hash values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, hash

I am new to ruby and Mongo and am looking for an answer to this...

I have a mongo database of records that contains records like this - with hashes embedded within hashes embedded within array

```
{
  "id =>1",
  "address" =>[
    {
      "number" => 1404,
      "street" =>"jasmine",
      "city" => "NY",
      "state" => "NY",
      "zip" => "02941"
    }, 
    {
      "number" => 2400,
      "street" =>"miner",
      "city" => "Boston",
      "state" => "MA",
      "zip" => "02760"
    },
    {etc..}
  ], 
  "geo" => { "lat" => 33.875, "lon" => -116.301 }     
  "first_name"=> "joe",
  "last_name" =>  "smith"
}

{ 
  "id" =>"2",
  "address" =>[{...},{...}, etc ],
  "geo" => {"lat" => 32.875, "lon" => -115.301 }, 
  "first_name"=> "john",
  "last_name"=>"doe"
}
```

and I want to find/return all records that include "street" == "jasmine", how do I reference "street" inside the find criteria?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoid / Mongodb and querying embedded documents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954520/mongoid-mongodb-and-querying-embedded-documents)

Answer (score 0):

if you're looping through each object:

```
objects_on_jasmine_street = []

NameOfObject.find_each do |object|
  if object['address'][0]['street'] # this will return street
     object_on_jasmine_street << object
  end
end

objects_on_jasmine_street
```

Comment: Little too "rubyesque" to be the best way to use a "database". Besides, there is a [much simpler way](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) when using MongoDB, as is what the question is asking.

Answer (score -1):

I believe searching array attributes in Mongo is pretty slow - consider converting your hashes for addresses into object instances. Then simply search as usual on your `Address` object rather than your `User` object. Also you may consider indexing the `street` attribute on your `Address` object so that it becomes faster when searching.